# Confusion regarding validation data set in Machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_LwzRVP7bg&list=PPSV&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

I was watching above youtube video , in chapter "Training Model" there were 3 sets discussed.
1)Training data set
2)Test data set
3)Validation data set

But i am confused in difference between these 3 types because in other resources of ML, i came across only two sets,Training data set and test data set, but here Validation data set is also discussed

But what is Validation data set and is it always necessary to include? and how it is different from Training data set & Test data set

[image]

Comment: look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_data_sets) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set)

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is a programming site, pure Machine Learning questions are not programming problems, so this is off-topic, there are much better places to ask this like ai.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in machine learning, the most discussed data sets are the **training** and the **test** sets where a model can learn a distribution (the training set) and evaluate its performance on unseen data (the test set).

In recent years, when enough data is present, a validation set has been introduced between those two sets to help with hyper-tuning (finding the best parameters for the models). It is similar to the test set because it is unseen data, but because we use it to tune the hyperparameters, we still need a final test set to see if those hyperparameters generalize well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you mean generally  only two data sets (training and testing) are sufficent and if data amount is large,,then 3rd data set(validation data set) should also be considered?

Comment: This is wrong, validation set did not appear "in recent years", and has nothing to do about enough data being present. I also suggest not to answer off-topic questions.

Comment: Guess my wording can be improved, so to add a little context : statistics did not appear in recent years and most of the tools used in machine learning come from various backgrounds in growing mature disciplines, so the validation set did not "appear", but its presence has increased in the recent years (last 10 from my experience?)

Comment: Although it is not directly related to the fact of data quantity (there is no relation between the quantity of data and if the validation set is possible or not), it is undirectly as creating a validation set takes another chunck of data out of your training set, and can be reconsidered when the quantity of data is low. This comes at the price of a less statistically valid model.

Comment: In agreement with @Dr.Snoopy comment, you will find more on topic questions and discussion on the datascience.stackexchange.com. With a simple search you can find already discussed questions such as : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46586/machine-learning-validation-set